# Wicket wants to serialize my Panel

Tags: serialization, wicket

When I access a specific page of my Wicket application, I get a NotSerializableException:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: my.package.MyPanel$1
```

But I can't explain why wicket should try to serialize the **Panel**. Any idea?

I don't know if it helps, but here is the code I use to add the panel:

```
final User profileUser = ...;
final IModel<User> loggedInUser = ...;
add(new MyPanel("panelid", new Model<MyObject>(new MyObject()))
    {
        @Override
        public boolean isVisible()
        {
            return profileUser != null && profileUser.equals(loggedInUser.getObject());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wicket serializes many things into the session as part of its approach to dealing with clustering.

Just about everything in Wicket (eventually) extends `Component` which implements `IClusterable` which extends `Serializable`.  So components such as panels that created in Wicket need to be serializable.

A common practice is to create `LoadableDetachableModel` classes wrapping your normal business objects with logic that stores only a key in session and reloads using that key.

If you use such models as fields in your components instead of the full business objects you'll strain the session memory much less.

Comment: thanks, but what does it mean in this case? should I wrap the MyPanel with a LoadableDetachableModel?

Comment: No.  A panel should be serializable without being wrapped.  But it or the class in which it is defined contains something not serializable, likely a business object, which should be wrapped.  I'd have to see a bit more code and maybe the not-serializable message to be sure what though.

Comment: sorry, found the problem. in the MyPanel I had an instance variable that was not Serializable. I couldn't see it, because I opened the wrong file (maybe it's a bit too late :-)  anyway: thanks for your great answer